# subtract NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a line

```
bookval_int_curr = [str1 intValue] - [str2 intValue];
```

But for some reason `bookval_int_curr` seems to be returning `nil`. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What type is `bookval_int_curr`? If it's an `int`, it can't be `nil`. If it's `nil`, it's the wrong type.

Comment: Both str1 and str2 are strings and get some values like 111122 and 1111 I want to subtract them as ints and store back as strings. 

bookval_int_curr is an NSInteger

Comment: Then your question is not accurate as an `NSInteger` cannot be `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Assume that str1 and str2 are strings. Then if they doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number, NSString would return 0. 0 - 0 = 0.
If you are trying to assign 0 to the object, then it's address would be nil.

Comment: yes, both str1 and str2 are strings and get some values like 111122 and 1111 I want to subtract them as ints and store back as strings.

Comment: NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [@"111122" intValue] - [@"1111" intValue]];

Comment: OR  NSString* s1 = @"111122"; NSString* s2 = @"1111"; NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [s1 intValue] - [s2 intValue]];  which is the same

Answer (score 3):

Check the types of str1, str2 and bookval_int_curr:

```
NSString *str1 = @"52";
NSString *str2 = @"50";

int bookval_int_curr = [str1 intValue] - [str2 intValue];
```

And check, that str1 and str2 is not equal `nil`.